# Java goes straight to Press any key to continue

Tags: java, mysql

I'm not sure what happened but I updated something on my code and then it kept going to "Press any key to continue..." when I ran it. I think I undid the last update completely but I'm not sure because it didn't do any good.

My code: http://pastebin.com/r2xVDhgC

Thanks! :)

New code:
http://pastebin.com/RiGDWkKQ

(Sorry the code thing for stackoverflow annoying me. I can't get it to work lol.)

Comment: Does the sql give you result data? `given.getInt("given")` has value return? Just to confirm, because I don't know what is in your db.

Answer (score 1):

This query is wrong:

```
String give = "SELECT `given` FROM `has_voted` " + 
              "WHERE `ip` LIKE '+thisIp.getHostAddress()'";
```

Presumably you wanted this:

```
String give = "SELECT `given` FROM `has_voted` " + 
              "WHERE `ip` = '" + thisIp.getHostAddress() + "'";
```

You also haven't defined `thisIp` anywhere.

Comment: @Thilo: Nope. Changed to `=`. Using `LIKE` would also work but it's misleading.

Comment: I know. I'm going to mess with the query later. I took off the IP part because that was part of the last update and I was making sure that it wasn't causing my error. I will put that back later.

Comment: I know it isn't defined I took it off temporarily so I could see if that was the problem somehow. :\ I just put the ip stuff back but it's still not working. I changed my code so that it would print the ip, it does print it, but it doesn't do anything else.

Comment: @AlexBenoit: Could you post your corrected code then we can see it? PS: Don't use a pastebin, just add the code to the question.

Comment: I have to use pastebin, I can't figure out the code thing on here unless I sit there doing 4 spaces before each line. :\ I pastebinned, hope you don't mind. http://pastebin.com/RiGDWkKQ

Comment: @AlexBenoit: Have you tried selecting the code then pressing Ctrl+K?

Comment: Nope. I'll try that next time I have to. Thanks.

Comment: Why not do it this time? It would make it more likely people will answer your question if they can see your code without having to follow a link. You just have to highlight the code then press Ctrl-K.